# Is there any way to politely ask this company to give me a response quicker, in regards to a role?

Tags: hiring-process, applications, hiring

I applied to Company A about 6 months ago, while also applying to other companies. Company A seemed like a really great fit, and was the role that I was most hoping to get. Eventually, I got acceptances from other jobs and when I didn't hear from Company A I assumed they were not moving forward with me (although I did send them an email politely asking if they had any updates for me). Awhile later I get the acceptance offer from Company A and they seemed very excited about hiring me, by which time I had already accepted another role (a freelance contract with Company B).

After my contract with Company B was finished, I reapplied and went through the application process with Company A. However, again it seems they are taking extremely long to get back to me - while other companies are taking much less time.

They are a mid sized company (between 25 - 50 employees I would imagine), so it's not like they are a brand new startup without an HR team. In an ideal world, I would just wait to hear from them, but considering bills and other expenses - I am probably going to have to take another offer from a different company.

Is there any way to politely ask them to take less time getting back to me about the position?

Comment: Where are you? I think workplace culture might be relevant here.

Comment: I think companies lose a lot of good candidates because they take such a long time.  Good people typically are not available for a long time.

Comment: That size company might not have a dedicated HR role - we don't. Mind you, our hiring managers are much more responsive. Take it as evidence of a disorganised organisation and look elsewhere

Comment: Just tell the HR people straight up. I would love to work with you but I have financial obligations and can't afford to wait. I have until [1 or 2 weeks from today insert the date here] until I will need to accept other offers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look seriously for other companies to work with, who have a more responsive HR team, it often says allot about a company's culture.

In the meantime, call company A. Be honest, I'd really love to work with you guys but can't wait forever, reluctantly give them days or weeks, insert your own time, to get back with an offer or you will have to accept other opportunities. If said time elapses, move on, if they can't see your benefit or worth, others will.

This way you hope for the best while seriously planning for the worst.

Best of luck

T

Answer (score 0):

While of course avoiding being rude about it, I don’t think you have to worry about a “polite” way of addressing this. A phone call (and actually getting to talk to one of the managers and/or person who interviewed you and liked you before - and presumably liked you again this second time around) and being frank with him or her will either secure that position for you or they will reconsider and not offer you the position because they didn’t like you being frank. Your current trajectory, it appears, guarantees the equivalent of the latter outcome, e.g. not having that job.

Again, this does not mean they answer the phone and you begin, “Hey slackers, when am I getting that offer obviously coming my way?!” But a simple statement of how much and/or why you think that job is the best fit for you and for them, your disappointment in only receiving the acceptance after you had taken on another role last time, and the fact that you didn’t then/aren’t now taking that other job because you are flighty or some such but rather you simply need an income... and you’d prefer that income come from them instead of elsewhere... should suffice! They are either human, and totally understand, or not, and don’t!